# Google Chrome DevTools site dimensions missing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

since the update to Version 49.0.2623.87 of Google Chrome im missing the overlay of the site which tells you (on resize) which dimensions the website has.

Anyone knows how to turn it on again, or is it removed?

It always saved some time for checking the styles for different breakpoints.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same version of chrome and for me when I right-click in the webpage and click on `Inspect`

When hovering over a  breakpoint you should see the dimensions in the top left

The [Chrome change log](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/) does not mention this feature being changed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this wasn't the problem. The Problem already answered in another question, which is linked to the topic.